# how to make a video play that has browser support?

Tags: php, mysql, video-streaming, html5-video

Is there any plugins required?

**I don't want users to download a plugin** in order to play a video. Is there any video player that supports playing the video in all browsers?

The code below is for *playing audio files*. Is there any way to play video files using the same code but renaming the "Content type" to that of which supports video?

I have no idea how this works. How do I even tell php that I want my video to stream which is saved in mysql?

```
<?php
header("Content-type: audio/mp3");
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
$db=mysql_select_db("test");
$query="select VideoClip from Video where VideoID=1";
$rs=mysql_query($query);
$song=mysql_result($rs,0,0);
echo $song;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Longer answer: all browser and operating systems have their preferred way of rendering video (see [this](http://www.diveintohtml5.org/video.html) for more explanation) so if you both want your users to not have to use a plugin AND use the same player, you're out of luck.

Comment: Is it possible by having a plugin? Which one is suitable to use?

Comment: Flash is most ubiquitous, but has performance issues off-Windows and isn't available for iOS devices. Mixing up Flash and HTML 5 `<video>` is a popular solution these days.

Comment: Read the link, but CodeCaster's url is a good pointer, that you'll understand once you read the one I gave you. Before HTML5 happened, people mostly used Flash as a video plugin. It does limit you to non iOS devices.

Comment: okay. give me some time to read. I'll get back to you later. thanks, by the way :)